# How do I tell the difference between tapping and holding the touchscreen?

Tags: unity, android, touch

I have a problem with the Unity game engine. I am making an Android game. I want to move an object by a small distance every time the user taps the screen, but not when the user holds the screen.

This is my current code. When the user holds the screen, the object keeps moving. I want to only move the object once the user touches the screen and not move it again until they released it:

```
void Update () {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
            transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y+0.1f);
        }
```

Comment: Your question was very hard to read. I rewrote it in proper English. Please say if I understood it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [touch phase](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchPhase.html) that is built into unity via the [Touch](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch.html) class?

```
void Update () {
    foreach (Touch finger in Input.touches)
    {
        if (finger.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y+0.1f);
        }
    }
}
```

This will check if the a finger has been detected and will move the object in the same way as the original code did, except the finger must have just been detected on the screen. If it is held the [Touch Phase](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchPhase.html) will change from Begin to either `Moved` or `Stationary`.

You might also want to look at [tap count](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-tapCount.html) if you need to check if the user is repeatedly tapping on screen.

Hope this helps

Comment: @Jam When this answer solved your problem, please accept it by clicking on the checkmark-icon next to it.